# Drag and Drop RESTful services

Tags: rest

I'm looking for a tool to post data to a RESTful web service and then display results - with zero programming.

Ultimately i'd like a drag and drop environment that I can use to build an application around the data with forms and business logic.

Comment: A "zero programming" question is pretty much off-topic for Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0):

Here at work we use Talend Studio.
Here is the [link](http://www.talend.com/index.php)

We use it for data transformation. It is pretty good. Lots of components.
It's open source and allows you to access RESTFul services as well.